# Change the style of particular elements of an array inside ng-repeat in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

E.g
I have an array of text like `$scope.array = [{text:'abc'}, {text:'pqr'}, {text:'xyz'}];`
Now along with `ng-repeat` I want to change the colour of the text of any particular element of the array. how to achieve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMO, we've multiple options to achieve that.

If you want to change single property then you can use `ng-style` but let say if you want to manipulate multiple properties then its preferable to use `ng-class`.

**ng-style**

The ngStyle directive allows you to set CSS style on an HTML element conditionally.

```
<div ng-repeat="contact in jsonContacts">
    <span ng-style="{'color':($first ?'red':'blue')}">{{data.row}}</span>
</div>
```

**ng-class**

The ngClass directive allows you to dynamically set CSS classes on an HTML element by databinding an expression that represents all classes to be added.

```
<div ng-repeat="i in array" ng-class="{'green': $last, 'blue': $first}">
    {{i.text}}
</div>
```

FYI,

The `ngRepeat` directive instantiates a template once per item from a collection. Each template instance gets its own scope, where the given loop variable is set to the current collection item, and $index is set to the item index or key.

`$first` boolean true if the repeated element is first in the iterator.

`$middle` boolean true if the repeated element is between the first and last in the iterator.

`$last` boolean true if the repeated element is last in the iterator.

**Official documentations**

[ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

[ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

[ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)

Hope this helps you :)

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.array = [{text:'abc'}, {text:'pqr'}, {text:'xyz'}];
});
```

```css
.green
{
  color: green;
}
.blue
{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    <h3>ng-style used</h3>
    
    <div ng-repeat="i in array" ng-style="{'color':($first ?'red':'blue')}">{{i.text}}</div>
    
    <br/>
    <h3>ng-class used</h3>
  <div ng-repeat="i in array" ng-class="{'green': $last, 'blue': $first}">{{i.text}}</div>
  </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @SaurabhPakhare : Glad to see that :)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using directives such as `ngClass` or `ngStyle`, to apply classes or style changes conditionally to certain HTML elements.

Let's assume you're listing your `$scope.array` elements:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="element in array">{{element.text}}</li>
</ul>
```

You could add a class called `.red` (that would change the text color to red) to an element if `text === 'pqr'`, but changing the above example to:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="element in array" ng-class="{'red': element.text === 'pqr'}">{{element.text}}</li>
</ul>
```

Similarly you can also use the directive `ng-style` to apply a style directly, avoiding new classes.
Since you're using an `ngRepeat`, you can also its iterator `$index` to apply classes/styles on more advanced cases such as first/last element, element index is odd/even, etc...

For more examples and clarifications, please check the official documentation for both directives:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-class` or `ng-style`, even including an auxiliar `function` in your controller to calculate that style.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array" ng-class="calculateClass(item)" ng-style="calculateStyle(item)">
    <!-- more stuff -->
</div>
```

**EDIT**

For your case it could be useful depending on what logic you want to apply to do something like

```
$scope.calculateStyle = function(item){
    var color;
    // Some logic to define color
    return {
        'color': color
    }
}
```